# Recupererar Bearer Token utilizando um ClientId e ClientSecret

Tags: jquery, web-service, api, rest, autenticação

Bom dia,

Preciso fazer uma chamada em uma API, possuo o ClientId e o ClientSecret, mas pelo que percebi, consigo fazer as chamadas utilizando o "authorization bearer".

Minha dúvida é como consigo transformar o id e secret neste "bearer token".

Estou utilizando JQuery para realizar as chamadas

Obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeiro você precisa requisitar o token no serviço de autenticação utilizando o seu ClientId e ClientSecret. Agora com o token "em mãos" você adiciona o header `Autorization` no seu request.

`Authorization: Bearer SEU_TOKEN`

Comment: Depois que eu vi que na documentação que nos enviaram, NÃO havia a URL para requisitar o token.